# UISearchDisplayController and related search result tableview

Tags: iphone

I have 2 UITableView with UISearchDisplayController on a same UIView.
How to determine which one of the two UITableView relates to the UISearchDisplay Controller?

Welcome any comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set tags both for the searchBars and tableViews, and check them appropriately in the callbacks of UISearchBarDisplayController and UITableView delegates.

For example:

```
-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchScope:(NSInteger)searchOption
{
    if (controller.searchBar.tag == 1)
    {
        [self.tableView1 reloadData];
        return YES;
    }
    else if (controller.searchBar.tag == 2)
    {
        [self.tableView2 reloadData];
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}
```

You can always use tags on UIViews to check "who is who" in your code.

Hope this helps.